# Selecting images from gallery table using SQL when the column is not null

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables, one to store users and other to store images. The user have 2 different photos, one for his profile and other for background display. The gallery table is used to store any photo, wheter it's from users, news, posts, products, etc...

So what I need to do is to select the profile and background photo from the gallery table when it's definied in the users table. This is how the tables look like

```
user
id | first_name | last_name | id_gallery_profile | id_gallery_background | ...

gallery
id | image | src
```

What I'm trying to do, without success, is this left join:

```
SELECT a.id, a.first_name, a.last_name
FROM user a
LEFT JOIN gallery.src AS 'profile_image' ON a.id_gallery_profile = gallery.id
LEFT JOIN gallery.src AS 'background_image' ON a.id_gallery_background = gallery.id
WHERE a.id = :userId
```

What am I doing wrong in here? Because the SQl return 0. Also, this query needs to work when the fields `id_gallery_profile` and `id_gallery_background` is null, because it may be a new user without any images yet, or the user just want to have no image for these fields.

Comment: You don't have the images in the SELECT list. And JOIN the tables, not the columns.

Comment: You JOIN to a table NOT a table.column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name,
       gp.src as profile_image, gb.src as background_image
FROM user u LEFT JOIN
     gallery gp
     ON u.id_gallery_profile = gp.id LEFT JOIN
     gallery gb
     ON u.id_gallery_background = gb.id
WHERE u.id = :userId;
```

Notes:

- Columns being returned go to the `SELECT`.
- When you are joining to the same table twice, use table aliases.
- The best table aliases are abbreviations of the table name.
- Use single quotes only for string and date constants.  Do not use them for column names.

Comment: I understand it now. I have done it before, but without the `gp` and `gb` difference, so I got the same image twice with different names. Now it's working. Thank you so much!